# Shukracharya the Guru of Asuras

Tags: shukracharya

There is a Shukracharya who is the Guru of Bali Chakravarthi in Vamana avatar of Vishnu. There is also Shukracharya who is the guru of Vrushaparva, during the time of Yayati forefather of the Kurus in Mahabharata. Are the two one and same?